# Existe algum decodificador de tabelas em Lua?

Tags: lua, table, tabela-html

Eu estou querendo saber isso pois quero saber se uma tabela é igual a outra,se ela é uma tabela vazia ou outra coisa.

Comment: O que é um decodificador de tabelas?

Comment: Uma tabela `t` é vazia sse `next(t)==nil`.

Comment: Para comparação de tabelas, veja http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2014-09/msg00421.html.

Comment: Deixa ver se eu entendi: você quer saber se um índice já existe ou ele ainda está vazio, isto é, se aquele item já foi inserido na tabela ou já existe é isso ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Tabela vázia?

Uma tabela é vázia se `next(t) == nil`, ou se `tamanhoDaArray <= 0` ou `tamanhoDaArray == 0`.

#### Comparando tabelas (x = y)

Há várias maneiras diferentes de verificar se uma tabela é igual outra.

Eu suponho que você já saiba que uma tabela é tanto *array* de valores quanto *dicionário* com pares de chaves e valores (a.k.a. hash). Uma array é sempre garantida de ser mais eficiente do que um hash (mesmo otimizado). Campos de hash são apenas necessários em casos raros e dinâmicos (na qual não adianta a técnica de otimização *"Inline Caching"* em acesso de campos).

A comparação que você quer depende da estrutura das tabelas `x` e `y`. O comentário de Luiz te leva à uma comparação simples e eficiente de tabelas, por completo, `deepcompare`. Abaixo deixo alguns exemplos¹ para comparar arrays apenas.

<sup>**[1]**: podem ser usados `rawget` e `rawset` em vez de `t[k]` e `t[k] = v`, caso não haver metatable.</sup>

**1) Comparando arrays superficialmente**

```
local function CompareArraySurface(x, y)
    local xl = #x;
    if xl ~= #y then return false; end

    for i = 1, #x do
        if x[i] ~= y[i] then
            return false;
        end
    end

    return true;
end

local print = (_ENV or _G).print;

print(
    CompareArraySurface({}, { 0, 0, 0 })          --> false,
  , CompareArraySurface({ 4, 1, 3 }, { 4, 1, 3 }) --  true,
  , CompareArraySurface({ { 1 } }, { { 1 } })     --  false
);
```

**2) Comparando arrays multi-dimensionais**

```
local CompareDims;

function CompareDims(x, y, dim)
    if dim <= 0 then
        return x == y;
    end

    local xl = #x;
    if xl ~= #y then return false; end

    for i = 1, xl do
        if not CompareDims(x[i], y[i], dim - 1) then
            return false;
        end
    end

    return true;
end

print(
  -- Array bidimensional (2 dimensões)
    CompareDims({ { 5 } }, { { 5 } }, 2) --> true,

  -- Array unidimensional (1 dimensão)
  , CompareDims({ { 5 } }, { { 5 } }, 1) -->  false
);
```